# METIS: undefined reference to `METIS_WPartGraphRecursive'

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, undefined-reference, metis

I have to compile a software that depends on METIS library, but whose CMake thing was written by disabling all the places where METIS was needed. Now, I have to re-enable that code again and thus the code depends now on METIS.

I installed metis-5.1.0 from source, and I wrote a CMake module to find it (actually I used [this one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/eigen/+/refs/heads/tools_r22/cmake/FindMetis.cmake)). I modify the `CMakeLists.txt` accordingly, basically adding the following lines

```
find_package(METIS REQUIRED)
if (METIS_FOUND)
    include_directories(SYSTEM ${METIS_INCLUDE_PATH})
else (METIS_FOUND)
    message (SEND_ERROR "This application cannot compile without METIS")
endif (METIS_FOUND)
```

and, at the end,

```
target_link_libraries(<my_executable> ${METIS_LIBRARIES})
```

After cmake, it seems everything is fine, because cmake prints:

```
-- Found METIS: /usr/local/include  
-- METIS libraries /usr/local/lib/libmetis.a
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to: <mylocation>
```

However, after I run make, I get

```
 undefined reference to `METIS_WPartGraphKway'
 undefined reference to `METIS_WPartGraphRecursive'
```

How can I solve?

**EDIT**:
As an additional information, when I compile with `make VERBOSE=1`, the linker seems to look for the right library, as it includes `/usr/local/lib/libmetis.a`, which corresponds to the location that cmake was specifying and which also exists. Moreover, when I look into the library with `nm /usr/local/lib/libmetis.a`, I see:

```
00000000000001c0 T METIS_WPartGraphKway
00000000000009c0 T METIS_WPartGraphRecursive
```

P.S.: In Ubuntu 17.04, I have tried with metis-5.1.0, metis-4.0.3 and also installing with `sudo apt-get install libmetis-dev`. In the latter case I find `libmetis.so` instead of `libmetis.a`, but, also in this case, this is correctly recognized by cmake, correctly looked for by the linker, but at the end I get the same error.

I also tried `sudo apt-get install libmetis-dev`, installing from source metis-5.1.0 and metis-3.0.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I had the same problem.
This seems a hard-to-solve error, as many people ask the same question in [this page](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/node/790) of the METIS formum.

I have also tried to add `-lmetis` at the end of the compilation command, as suggested [here](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/node/790)

As an additional information, I did a `grep WPartGraphKway` in the METIS source folder. In version 5.1.0 there is no such string. In version 4.0.3 there is.

Comment: Are you sure that "unresolved references" reported for the executable you show, and not for another executable/library? With `VERBOSE=1` option to `make` you may see full command lines use for compile and link, and check that linking with metis library is actually performed.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question with the output from `VERBOSE=1`

Answer (score 1):

I solved doing this:

- I install `metis-3.0`
- I run `cmake` for my software
- I run `make VERBOSE=1`
- I copy the last `gcc` command being printed
- I paste it, I add at the end of the command `-lmetis` and execute the command

Note that, if I repeat the same operation with `metis-5.1.0`, it does not work and I have the same error that I wrote in the first post.